# Being a product - from homology to topology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology, surgery-theory, persistent-homology

The famous Kunneth formula expresses the homology of a product manifold as the tensor product of the two algebras.

Now suppose we know that a manifold $X$ has a decomposition $H_*(X) \simeq A \otimes B$ as algebras. When is $X$ actually a product of manifolds?

**What I thought.** Firstly, one should find manifolds $M, N$ such that $H_*(M) \simeq A, H_*(N) \simeq B$. Secondly, there should be a topological map from $M \times N \to X $ or viceversa that induces such isomorphism. At last, one should turn this homological (weak?) equivalence into a diffeomorphism, which could be a consequence of the smooth structure. I am almost sure here surgery theory comes into play, so that the answer could be much easier for higher dimensions. In my mind, each of these steps would produce some obstructions.

**Motivation.** Suppose you a random data set distributed among a product manifold $M\times N$. You want to understand that this geometry hides a product decomposition. The modern toolkit we have is persistent homology, and I was thinking if there is a way to catch the existence of a decomposition via persistent homology. The very special case of a product of $S_1$'s or in general spheres is probably easier because of the 'thin' homology they have.

Comment: Are you working in some specific characteristic? The Künneth formula is a tensor product over a field (and then, only for finite-type spaces). Over a PID you get $\mathrm{Tor}$ terms. Over an arbitrary ring...

Comment: Usually one considers **co**homology to be an algebra. What is the algebra structure of $H_*(M)$ if $M$ is just a differential (or topological) manifold?

Comment: Suppose you work over the rationals, us ecohomology, and assume everything is simply-connected. The the Sullivan-Barge Theorem may tell you when each of hte factors $A$ and $B$ is the cohomology of a manifold: https://mathoverflow.net/a/115921/8103. This method might only give you a rational homotopy equivalence, but it's a start.

Comment: For your motivation, I think one problem is that a product requires two projections, so you need to analyse the data set to find two directions (sort of generalised principal axes) that have good properties. You want to then project the data set in those two directions (Big problems as those axes may not be straight!) I think your approach may need some refining before the first question links well with the motivation.

Comment: @Najib: since mine is mère curiosity, I am ok with studying rational and finite field homology.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwag: I always get confused with such products, but I think transversal intersection of submanifolds almost always does the job. Formally, let us restrict to compact manifolds without boundary, and use (non-oriented) Poincaré duality to transport the cohomological product. Does this sound convincing?

Comment: @TimPorter: that's a fair point. Maybe one can mix the two methods: decompose persistent homology and find the "right axes" by looking at the (co) homology. Intuitively, the axis that annihilates one factor should annihilate all the persistent cycles coming from that factor. This guess-and-decompose method could be more well-suited for the TDA application